# listview recyle view issue?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

i have a listview where i have a view for which i have set a visibility gone.now on button click on one of the child elements of this listview i want to show this view,but it is showing in multiple positions in the listview.I know that this is due to the recycled views but i am unable to implement a solution for it.Do anyone have suggestions,this is my code

```
if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_open_orders_row, null);
        fulfilledView = new FulFilledOrdersHolder();

        fulfilledView.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_open_order_title);
        fulfilledView.order_datetime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_open_order_datetime);
        fulfilledView.customer_address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_open_order_address);
        fulfilledView.customer_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_open_order_name);
        fulfilledView.product_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_open_order_price);

        fulfilledView.product_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imv_open_orders);

        fulfilledView.details = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_open_orders_details);
        fulfilledView.call = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_open_orders_call);

        fulfilledView.slide = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sliding);
        fulfilledView.slide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        convertView.setTag(fulfilledView);
    }
    else
    {
    fulfilledView = (FulFilledOrdersHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    fulfilledView.title.setText(values.get(position).getTitle());
    fulfilledView.order_datetime.setText(values.get(position).getOrder_datetime());


    fulfilledView.details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                fulfilledView.slide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add one boolean flag in list item model class which is by default value is false  :

```
private boolean isSlideVisible;

public boolean isSlideVisible() {
   return isSlideVisible;
}

public void setSlideVisible(boolean isSlideVisible) {
    this.isSlideVisible = isSlideVisible;
}
```

Now change status of flag vice-verse for particular item and notify adapter :

```
fulfilledView.details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      if(values.get(position).isSlideVisible()){
         values.get(position).setSlideVisible(false);
      }else{
         values.get(position).setSlideVisible(true);      
      }
      notifyDataSetChanged ()
    }
 });
```

Show slide view base on flag value :

```
if(values.get(position).isSlideVisible()){
   fulfilledView.slide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
   fulfilledView.slide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked there was some problem with my code i resolved it and applied the way described by you it worked for me